# Magento navigation menu

Tags: php, magento, menu, hyperlink, navigation

I am trying to reorganize my navigation menu. I want it to have only one product page button and a couple of CMS pages. I don`t want any categories on it. I know how to put additional buttons to the menu, but if I try to remove the category the whole menu disappears. Any suggestion? I am runing the latest magento with a custom theme.
P.S. I tried to edit the top.phtml site but I am not very confident with coding.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can change menu as you want to customize and want to add your link

```
app\design\frontend\your_package\your_theme\template\page\html
```

add your link to **topmenu.phtml**

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: I don`t have that file. I forgot to mention that it`s magento community edition. I tried to edit app\design\frontend\default\your_theme\template\catalog\navigation\top.phtml without success

Comment: i have update my answer. Please check will sure help you

Answer (score 0):

You can read this tutorial - [Adding Page Links to the Main Menu](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar)